# Angular service worker dataGroups maxAge Is not working

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, angular-service-worker

I have an angular application where I am using a service worker, and I am using "dataGroups" to set the "maxAge" for a specific url of an image.
My problem is that the image is being loaded from the service worker even though it is expired and I am setting the "strategy" to "freshness" .
Here is my "ngsw-config.json" file:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/service-worker/config/schema.json",
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"
        ]
      }
    }, {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**",
          "/*.(eot|svg|cur|jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "dataGroups": [
    {
      "name" : "imagecaching",
      "cacheConfig" : {
        "maxAge": "20s",
        "strategy" : "freshness",
        "timeout" : "3m",
        "maxSize" : 100
      },
      "urls" : [
        "https://www.lifewire.com/thmb/AhPDeQ36tu-_rIkvJuKehIUbRbk=/768x0/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc()/GettyImages-831864150-5c32ba8b46e0fb0001b18e2b-32fd8792359f4acd973b4bd6c24e999e.jpg"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

could you please explain when will the image be loaded from the network instead of the service worker?